# how to create a trigger with Sqlite in django

Tags: django, sqlite, triggers

I have a "quenstion" and "comments" model I wanted to automatically delete any questions that will not be commented after 30 days of its publication

Comment: you can use celery:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/

Comment: Use celery with crontab

Answer (score 0):

The nature of SQLite (being a library rather than a server) means that it doesn't have any built in scheduling. So you can't just do this in the database.

You can make a cleanup query and run it every so often though. The simplest way to do it would be to make the cleanup script a custom `manage.py` command, and run it with cron or systemd timers.